# How can I grab and display input values after I submit the form

Tags: php

So I'm in PHP 101 and I first assignment we have to make a simple form and do a few things with the data. Right now I can't seem to display the user info to the screen after I hit submit? Right now I want to check and see if the fields were left blank then display a message when the user tries to submit telling them they left out information.

```
<html>
<style>
    body {
        background-color: grey;
    }
</style>    
<body>

<form action="firstform.php" method="POST">

First Name: <input type="text" name="fName" require></input></br>
Age: <input type="text" name="age" require></input></br>
Are you a vegan?</br>
<label for="yes">Yes</label><input type="radio" name="q" value="yes"></input>
<label for=noq">No</label><input type="radio" name="q" value="no"></input>
<label for="maybe">Maybe</label><input type="radio" name="q"value="maybe"></input></br>

<input type="submit" value="submit"></type>

</form>

<?php
        if(isset($_POST['fName']) && isset($_POST['age'])) {
            $name = $_POST['fName'];
            $age = $_POST['age'];

            echo "yoooooooooooooo";
            echo $age;
        }
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can use empty() to check if that array post request is empty and not set

Comment: I tried this, now the problem is when I refresh the page its showing the message because the fields are empty. But it needs to show after the forms been submitted

Comment: Ask yourself the question "When is this PHP code evaluated?". The answer is that this is done before the page is send to the browser, and before anyone can input anything in this form.  A (first) check for valid input is mostly done in Javascript, because that can be done client-side (before submit).

Comment: On a side note, as you can see by the code highlighting, you have omitted an open quote `"`.

Comment: so you need to check if form has been submitted 1st - if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){//do whatever} This way your code will execute only when form has been submitted

Comment: otherwise your code runs right away, when your post variables are empty ...

Comment: @AngelDeykov Thank you that helped a lot! Is there a way to remove the form after the user hits submit? So I can show results etc.

Comment: yes use jquery or javascript, you can find tons of examples of show/hide elements from you page, in your case the form element

Comment: _“Is there a way to remove the form after the user hits submit?”_ - if you can _process_ the data only if any was actually sent now by doing a check with `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')` - well then you can probably only output the form in the _other_ case, right?

Answer (score 0):

use a name for submit button

```
if (isset($_POST['name_of_submit'])) {
    if(empty($_POST['fName']) || empty($_POST['age']))
       echo "<div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
              Left out information
            </div>";
 }
```